# Une salutation ou une question typique pour les pêcheurs

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

En russe, quand je vois une person qui pêche au bord de la rivière, je peux demander:

> "Клюет?" (Est-ce que les poissons mordent?)

C'est une question typique pour commencer le dialogue. Vous pouvez même l'utiliser au lieu de "bonjour".

Y a-t-il des phrases ou des questions typiques pour la pêche/les pêcheurs en Français?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On peut faire exactement la même chose en français et même aussi dire bonjour tout à la fois ; c'est seulement que l'on peut se passer de dire bonjour, ne pas se méprendre ; je crois que ça ne peut pas être différent en russe ;  en français, cependant, ça prendra deux mots ; il faut poser la question suivante ;

- Ça mord ?

« Mord » vient du verbe courant « mordre » qui signifie « saisir entre les dents puis enfoncer les dents dans ce qui a été saisi ».